# Best possible SEO way of forcing the iframe'd page to reload as parent

Tags: javascript, html, http-headers, redirect

```
<html>
   <iframe src="iWantToBeTheParent.html" />
</html>
```

I think this is a JavaScript task, it would be nice to handle the redirection with htaccess though since my code will inside an iframe I'm looking for a method that initiates from inside the iframe source which would make the iframe url load as the parent.

*I only have access to the iframe source page's html.*
**Would it be possible to send a 301 HTTP redirect as well?**

**EDIT**: I could use php to print out the url of the iframe page as a JavaScript variable if needed.

Comment: Do you have access to the iframe's source, or the parent's source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try some javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        if (top.location!= self.location) {
            top.location = self.location.href
        }
    //-->
</script>
```

Courtesy of:
http://usablelayout.com/articles/automatically-break-out-iframe

This will set the top level location (the main page) to the location of the page where the javascript is located (inside the iframe).

Comment: Does anyone know if we can set HTTP Headers with JavaScript while doing the above redirect?